# More problems with FFmpeg not recognizing the directory I'm sending it to

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg

I am creating a program that takes an audio file, breaks it up into 30-second audio files, and sends those files to Google's Speech Recognition API to transcribe the audio. I'm using FFmpeg to break up the original audio file and make the 30-second files. It was working for about 20 minutes and I didn't change anything but now it's giving me an error saying that no such file or directory exists.

Here is the error it gives me:

```
C:\Users\hmkur\Desktop\Python\Transcribing_Audio_GoogleAPI_Python>ffmpeg -i source/valve.flac -f segment -segment_time 30 -c copy parts/out%01d.flac
ffmpeg version 4.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'source/valve.flac':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:11:42.54, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 129 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
[segment @ 000001f8e84bd100] Opening 'parts/out0.flac' for writing
[segment @ 000001f8e84bd100] Failed to open segment 'parts/out0.flac'
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): No such file or directory
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

Both the folder "source" with "valve.flac" exists as well as the folder "parts" and the files "out0.flac", etc. I was originally trying in the wav file format, switched to flac and it worked for about 20 minutes then stopped working.

Comment: Your source `valve.flac` isn't actually FLAC, so you can't use `-c copy` here.

Comment: @Gyan why isn't it actually FLAC file format? How can you tell it's not FLAC? When I look at the properties for the files, it says they're .flac format

Comment: See the line `Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'source/valve.flac'`. It belongs to the MP4 family of files.

Comment: @Gyan how would I get the file to be true flac or have ffmpeg recognize it as flac?

Comment: Whichever app is generating the source files has to correctly name files. If that is outside your control, run `ffprobe -show_entries format=format_name -v 0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1 yourfile.ext`. That will print the detected format. Check if it says `flac`. If it does, keep `-c copy` else remove it.

Comment: @Gyan I got valve.flac to be flac but it's the same error:
`Input #0, flac, from 'source/valve.flac':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:09:56.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1190 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit)
[segment @ 000002247d816540] Opening 'parts/out0.flac' for writing
[segment @ 000002247d816540] Failed to open segment 'parts/out0.flac'
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): No such file or directory
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times`

Comment: What's the result of `cd C:\Users\hmkur\Desktop\Python\Transcribing_Audio_GoogleAPI_Python\parts`?

Comment: @Gyan I removed the parts folder and parts in the command, I put everything in the same directory and it's working now. I don't know why it didn't want to move into another folder but it's working this way! Now Google's API is converting the files and gets almost all the way saying it has completed most of them and then throw me this error:

Comment: @Gyan It says that the files may not be in their native file format even though I checked and they are all native flac